# Can't access Prometheus Postgres exporter installed in kubernetes: connection refused

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I was trying to use prometheus to do monitoring in kubernetes. We have some metrics stored in an external postgres database, so first I would like to install a postgres exporter. I used this helm chart to install it: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-postgres-exporter
And filled values.yaml with my database info. After installing, it provided me with the instruction below:

```
NOTES:
1. Get the application URL by running these commands:
  export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace default -l "app=prometheus-postgres-exporter,release=veering-seastar" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
  echo "Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080 to use your application"
  kubectl port-forward $POD_NAME 8080:80
```

But when I try to forward the port, I got connection refused:

```
Handling connection for 8080
E0801 19:51:02.781508   22099 portforward.go:331] an error occurred forwarding 8080 -> 80: error forwarding port 80 to pod 37a502b22a15fefcbddd3907669a448c99e4927515fa6cdd6fd87ef774993b6b, uid : exit status 1: 2018/08/02 02:51:02 socat[32604] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:80, 16): Connection refused
```

However the pod is working properly when I do kubectl describe, and there only three of logs there:

```
time="2018-08-02T01:08:45Z" level=info msg="Established new database connection." source="postgres_exporter.go:995"
time="2018-08-02T01:08:45Z" level=info msg="Semantic Version Changed: 0.0.0 -> 9.5.12" source="postgres_exporter.go:925"
time="2018-08-02T01:08:46Z" level=info msg="Starting Server: :9187" source="postgres_exporter.go:1137"
```

Is there anything I'm missing here to get it working and be able to see the metrics via port forwarding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> time="2018-08-02T01:08:46Z" level=info msg="Starting Server: :9187" source="postgres_exporter.go:1137"

It looks like the [chart notes text](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus-postgres-exporter/templates/NOTES.txt#L13) just has a copy-paste error, since the port number is not `:80` but rather `:9187`, which is great because it squares with the [postgresql exporter port](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/wiki/Default-port-allocations) in their registry.

So, it should be:

```
kubectl port-forward 9187:9187 &
sleep 2
curl localhost:9187/metrics
```

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't notice it. Cuz it has port:80 and targetport:9187, and I got them messed up. Thanks!!!!!